# What would be the fastest way to intersect two bitsets into a new BitSet in Java?

Tags: java, performance, bitset, set-intersection

Is there something faster in time than this:

```
// say we alread have BitSet bs1 and bs2
BitSet bs3 = (BitSet) bs1.clone();
bs3.and(bs2);
```

Maybe convert to ints and add as numbers and then convert back to `BitSet`?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just first time using this class and maybe there is something faster?

Comment: If you mean shorter code, no, there's nothing shorter.

Comment: I mean faster in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative I can think of is

```
Bitset newBitset = new Bitset(bs1.size());
newBitset.or(bs1).and(bs2);
```

You'll need to time the two to see which is faster; my alternative may be slightly faster since you're not calling an overriding method and you're not doing any casting.

Comment: I'll have to note that I don't expect a downcasting (which is merely a type-check at runtime) very exensive, and I expect the compiler (either one) to optimise it away completely just after inlining `clone`.

Comment: I agree; also, calling an overriding method isn't that expensive, and might also be optimized away by the compiler

Comment: I would like to see a benchmark. Also, I wouldn't be very surprised if the JIT compiler produced the _same_ machine code, bit by bit. Even the resulting capacity is the same in both cases.

Comment: I'll benchmark it after work unless Sophie Sperner does so before me

Comment: Nice, thank you, when I finish the code, will try your approach and benchmark it. It will not be too soon, some time later though :)

Comment: I benchmarked it on a 64-bit Windows machine running JRE7 using 128-bit BitSets (one had every other bit set to true, the other had every third bit set to true), and on average my alternative ran 20% slower than `clone`. I'm guessing that `clone` is able to reconstruct the new bitset using a low-level copy mechanism, e.g. an array copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the speed, I would guess that practically nothing BitSet does will be nearly as fast as bitwise operations on integers -- &, |, etc.  Of course, you don't have a number of operations on bit-wise-handled integers that you do in BitSet objects; you give that up when you decide to go to maximum speed.